# What happens when you cast a spell with multiple copies of Krark, the thumbless

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-stack

Using the partner commanders [Krark, the Thumbless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrark%2c%20the%20Thumbless%5d) and [Sakashima of a Thousand Faces](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSakashima%20of%20a%20Thousand%20Faces%5d). Krark has the ability:

> Whenever you cast an instant or sorcery spell, flip a coin. If you lose the flip, return that spell to its owner's hand. If you win the flip, copy that spell, and you may choose new targets for the copy.

With Sakashima removing he legend rule (and likely entering as a copy of Krark) it gets complicated. The question is what happens to the other Krark triggers when you lose a flip? Do they still resolve and copy the spell, or do they fizzle with the spell no longer on the stack?

Answer (score 1):

On Gather, Krark has a ruling that covers this situation:

> If you win the flip, but the spell that caused Krark’s triggered ability to trigger isn’t on the stack anymore (most likely because it was countered), the copy is still created.

This means that the flips still happen and the copies will still be created even if the spell has already been removed from the stack. In the ruling they suggest because of countering, but in this case it will work the same way for a earlier Krark returning the spell to hand.

Comment: Can you - or anyone reading this - please provide a rules reference? Last known information rules, as far as I can tell, only apply to sources of abilities, not targets. The spell to be copied here is the target of the copy ability, not the target.

Comment: The ability in question does not have a target. It is just referring to another object. And a spell or ability can get last known information from any specific object, not just the source. See rule 608.2g